# deepwater with tensorflow on RHEL6

Tags: python, tensorflow, h2o

I am trying to get Python + deepwater + tensorflow to run on RHEL 6.7.  Using `conda`, I have installed `python 3.6.0`, `tensorflow 1.1.0` and also `gcc 4.8.5`.  TF is working fine.

I have installed the following libraries using `pip install`: `h2o-3.11.0.3904-py2.py3-none-any.whl` and `h2o-3.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl`.

I tried to run the following example from the h2o tutorial

```
import h2o
from h2o.estimators.deepwater import H2ODeepWaterEstimator

h2o.init()

train = h2o.import_file("https://h2o-public-test-data.s3.amazonaws.com/bigdata/laptop/mnist/train.csv.gz")

features = list(range(0,784))
target = 784

train[target] = train[target].asfactor()

model = H2ODeepWaterEstimator(epochs=100, activation="Rectifier", hidden=[200,200], ignore_const_cols=False, 
    mini_batch_size=256, input_dropout_ratio=0.1, hidden_dropout_ratios=[0.5,0.5], stopping_rounds=3, 
    stopping_tolerance=0.05, stopping_metric="misclassification", score_interval=2, score_duty_cycle=0.5,
    score_training_samples=1000, score_validation_samples=1000, nfolds=5, gpu=False, seed=1234, backend="tensorflow")

model.train(x=features, y=target, training_frame=train)
```

The following exception is thrown

```
Exception: Unable to initialize the native Deep Learning backend: Cannot find TensorFlow native library for OS: linux, architecture: x86_64. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/java/README.md for possible solutions (such as building the library from source).
```

Is there anything else that I am missing?  Would I need to build the bits from scratch for this platform?

Comment: Why are you installing two wheels? Where did you get them from?

Comment: `http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/3904/Python/h2o-3.11.0.3904-py2.py3-none-any.whl`  and  `http://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-deepwater/public/nightly/latest/h2o-3.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl`

Comment: Should I install only the latter?  it seems that one uninstalls the other before installing.  I have tried one before the other and the other way around.

Comment: you only need to install the one under "H2O with GPU-Enabled Machine Learning" from this website https://www.h2o.ai/download/

Comment: We don't support RedHat. To get it to work you would have to rebuild it. It's possible to do, but I would recommend you to run the docker image instead, since it's just ready to use. Instructions: https://github.com/h2oai/deepwater#pre-release-docker-image